# convert NaN values to 0.0 in data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to convert "NaN" values to 0.0 in my data frame but always getting 0 but i want in decimal points.

I am trying this way

```
 

     T1[ ,2]<-ifelse(T1[ ,2]=="NaN",paste0(as.character(0.0),"%"),paste0(T1[ ,2],"%"))
```

this is my output i am trying to change it to 0.0 Values in output

[image]

Comment: Try `is.nan(T1[, 2])` instead of `T1[, 2] == "NaN"`.

Comment: like this way ...???
T1[ ,2]<-ifelse(is.nan(T1[, 2]),paste0(as.character(0.0),"%"),paste0(T1[ ,2],"%"))

Comment: its giving NaN% in rsullt

Comment: You need to make a reproducible example, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you read the link I suggested? Images for data/code are not very useful on Stack Overflow, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data frame looks like this (with your second column called Cat2):

```
df <- data.frame(Category = c("HR", "Wing", "Soft"), Cat2 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN), N = c(0, 0, 0))
```

You can do this if you just want the second to read 0.0 if it contains an NA value:

```
df$Cat2[is.na(df$Cat2)] <- "0.0"
```

Or, if you want the percentage symbol after it too:

```
df$Cat2[is.na(df$Cat2)] <- "0.0%"
```